How to get the Symbollnfo (or TypeSymbol) of ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax via MemberAccessExpressionSyntax
I use Roslyn to analyze field initializations. One of the analysis target is the following field.
private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<int, int> _Map =
   new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }.ToImmutableDictionary();

When this field is analyzed with the following code, SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo works when invoked by the AnalyzeInvocation method.
However, it does not work (throws an ArgumentException) when invoked by the AnalyzeObjectCreation method via the recursive call of the AnalyzeExpression method.
I don't understand why this happens. How can I get the Symbollnfo (or TypeSymbol) of Dictionary<int, int> (not ImmutableDictionary<int, int>) correctly?
my DiagnosticAnalyzer Class
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)  
{
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);  
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeFieldInitialization, SyntaxKind.FieldDeclaration);
}

private static void AnalyzeFieldInitialization(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)  
{
    if (context.Node is not FieldDeclarationSyntax syntax) return;

    var variableSyntax = syntax.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();  
    if (variableSyntax is null) return;

    var symbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(variableSyntax);  
    if (symbol == null) return;

    // variableSyntax.Initializer?.Value is of type InvocationExpressionSyntax  
    AnalyzeExpression(context, variableSyntax.Initializer?.Value, symbol.Locations[0], symbol.Name);
}

private static void AnalyzeExpression(
    SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, ExpressionSyntax expression, Location location, object arg)
{
    switch (expression)
    {
        case ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax objectCreation:
            {
                AnalyzeObjectCreation(context, objectCreation, location, arg);
                return;
            }
        case InvocationExpressionSyntax invocation:
            {
                AnalyzeInvocation(context, invocation, location, arg);
                return;
            }
        case MemberAccessExpressionSyntax memberAccess:
            {
                if (memberAccess.Expression is ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax objectCreation)
                {
                    AnalyzeObjectCreation(context, objectCreation, location, arg);
                }
                return;
            }
    }
}

private static void AnalyzeInvocation(
    SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, InvocationExpressionSyntax expression, Location location, object arg)
{
    // GetSymbollnfo works for InvocationExpressionSyntax InvocationExpression 
    // new Dictionary<int, int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }.ToImmutableDictionary()

    var info = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(expression, context.CancellationToken);
    if (info.Symbol is not IMethodSymbol method) return; 

    MyAnalysis(context.Compilation, method.ReturnType);

    AnalyzeExpression(context, expression.Expression.WithoutTrivia(), location, arg);
 }

private static void AnalyzeObjectCreation(
    SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context, ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax expression, Location location, object arg)
 {
    // GetSymbolInfo does not work (throws an ArgumentException) for
    // expression.Type = GenericNameSyntax GenericName Dictionary<int, int>

    var symbollnfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(expression.Type, context.CancellationToken);
    if (symbollnfo.Symbol is ITypeSymbol typeSymbol)
    {
        MyAnalysis(context.Compilation, typeSymbol);
    }

    var initializerExpressions = expression.Initializer?.Expressions.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<ExpressionSyntax>();
    foreach (var expressionSyntax in initializerExpressions)
    {
        AnalyzeExpression(context, expressionSyntax, location, arg);
    }
}

private  static void MyAnalysis(Compilation compilation, ITypeSymbol typeSymbol) 
{
     // Execute my analysis.
}


Is there an error message with that ArgumentException?

@nalka “Syntax node is not within syntax tree. “

For some reasons (as it often does with analysers in my experience) when debugging with the VS experimental instance it never goes into AnalyzeFieldInitialization (but it reaches Initialize several times), what did you use to test your code?

@nalka I use a VS debbuger to test my analysis code. It never fails to reach AnalyzeFieldInitialization, but always throws an ArgumentException (“Syntax node is not within syntax tree. “) in the situation I stated above. It does not seem to be the problem of my testing environment.
